# How to verify if atom package launched properly in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, linter

I installed linter-php and also tried to configure it in config.cson as following

```
"linter-php":
    executablePath: "C:\xampp\php"
```

but I don't see any indication that something that is related to linter affects atom display. How can I verify that this package (or any package in general) is working properly when atom is running?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: you can find all active packages by running `atom.packages.activePackages` in Atom's [developer console](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#check-for-errors-in-the-developer-tools).

However, your problem could be caused by providing an invalid path. Backslashes need to be escaped in CSON, so your config should look like this:

```
"linter-php":
    executablePath: "C:\\xampp\\php"
```

Comment: Thanks. meanwhile, I am waiting to solve this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138728/atom-ide-isnt-launched so I could verify if your answer works...